# json custom object_hook is not being called in python

Tags: python, json

I have wrote a custom hook which works when input string is valid dict in python, but it doesn't works when it is valid list.

`[1,2]` is a valid json but if I pass this to `json.loads` with my custom hook, the hook is not being called.

```
import json

def my_hook(object):
    print("{} : {}".format(type(object), object))
    return object


l = json.dumps([1,2])
d = json.dumps({'a': 8})

# my_hook is being called in this case
json.loads(d, object_hook=my_hook)

# my_hook is not being called in this case
json.loads(l, object_hook=my_hook)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't manage `JSON` `array` deserialization using `object_hook`, only `JSON` `object`s (like `d` in your example), as it said in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)

> `object_hook` is an optional function that will be called with the result of any **object literal** decoded (a `dict`). The return value of `object_hook` will be used instead of the `dict`. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders (e.g. JSON-RPC class hinting).

If you really need to handle `array`s, you can write your post-processing function and walk through every node and modify `list` objects.

BTW `object` is a name of [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object), so I suggest you to rename it to `obj`/`object_`/something else.